# How to display only date from firestore Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have data stored in `Firestore` with the field traveldate and I'm trying to print the data in `Text(document['traveldate'].toString())` but in text, it shows like in UI `Timestamp(seconds=xxxx, nanoseconds=0)`.

```dart
Card(child: ListTile(title: Text(document['Startdate'].toString(),
style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(fontStyle: FontStyle.normal)))),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert a Firestore Timestamp to a Date like this:

```
DateTime date = document['Startdate'].toDate();
```

And if you want to display it with a specific text format you can convert your date like this:

```
String dateFormatted = DateFormat('dd MMM, yyyy').format(date);
```

Based on your pasted code you can do this:

```
Card(child: ListTile(title: Text(document['Startdate'].toDate(),
style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(fontStyle: FontStyle.normal)))),
```

Comment: It doesn't give me the toDate() method.. Could you please help me?

Comment: .toDate() is a Timestamp function. Timestamp is provided by Firebase cloud firestore not by default flutter material.Try by import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

Comment: Hey Its solved.. thank you...

Comment: Ok thanks for the info. In case my answer helped you consider marking it as accepted for others

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
Card(
child: ListTile(title: Text((document['Startdate'] as Timestamp).toDate().toString(),
style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(fontStyle: FontStyle.normal)))
),
```

Don't forget to import

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
```

Comment: The argument of DateTime cant be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. Please help

Comment: Hey Its solved.. thank you...

Comment: Oh i just forgot to add toString() call to it.